# How to extract all the frames from video file instead only one frame?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, c#

I tried this parameters:

```
"-r 1 -i" + ts + " -r 1" + _infilepath+"\"$filename%03d.png"
```

but it does nothing it's not extracting any frames in the output window:

[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiTaS.jpg)

the original paramters are:

```
"-ss " + ts + " "
                    + "-i \"" + _infilepath + "\" "
                    + "-frames:v 1 "
                    + "-hide_banner -y -sn "
                    + "\"" + outfile + "\""
```

but this extract only one the first frame.

_ffpath contains the ffmpeg exe file
_infilepath contains the mp4 video file
outfile contains the saved frame file

The method CommandRunner is in the bottom.

```
private void Extract(){
            if (_infilepath.Length == 0) {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "The input file cannot be empty", "Validation error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.None);
                return;
            }
            if (_outfilepath.Length == 0) {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "The output file cannot be empty", "Validation error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.None);
                return;
            }
            File.Delete(_outfilepath);
            var exf = new ExtractProgressForm();
            exf.Show(this);
            string ts = tsin.Text.Replace(" ", "0");
            string outfile = _outfilepath.Replace("%t", ts.Replace(":", "-").Replace(".", "_"));
            _extractcr = new CommandRunner(
                _ffpath, 

                "-r 1 -i" + ts + " -r 1" + _infilepath+"\"$filename%03d.png"

                /*"-ss " + ts + " "
                + "-i \"" + _infilepath + "\" "
                + "-frames:v 1 "
                + "-hide_banner -y -sn "
                + "\"" + outfile + "\""*/,
                false
            );
```

The method CommandRunner:

```
public CommandRunner(string fname, string args = "", bool autostart = true){
            _fname = fname;
            _args = args;

            if (!_fileExists())
                throw new FileNotFoundException(fname + " cannot be found");

            Proc = new Process();
            Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            Proc.StartInfo.FileName = _fname;
            if (_args.Length > 0)
                Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = _args;
            Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            if (autostart)
                Start();
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786669/extract-all-video-frames-as-images-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to extract all the frames:

Create a folder called Frames....
and:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 "Frames\%07d.jpg"
```